# How to add variables to boolean expression and get conjunctive normal form?

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

I have the boolean expression `(a && !b)`. I want to add variables `c`, `d` into the expression and then have *Mathematica* transform the expression into conjunctive normal form. I would like it to go something like this:

```
a&&!b
  = (a && !b && c) || (a && !b && !c)
  = (a && !b && c && d) || (a && !b && c && !d) || (a && !b && !c && d) || 
    (a && !b && !c && !d)
```

Although a human can do this easily, how can can I get *Mathematica* to do it? What are the commands?

Comment: Take a look at `BooleanConvert` and *forms* it has available. But I don't know how to use it for your purpose :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't now that I really understand your question, but from a pure expression manipulation perspective this might be useful:

```
Or @@ And @@@ Tuples[{{a && ! b}, {c, ! c}, {d, ! d}}]
```

> (a && ! b && c && d) || (a && ! b && c && ! d) || (a && ! b && ! c && 
>      d) || (a && ! b && ! c && ! d)

The same operation a bit more concisely:

```
Or @@ Tuples[{a && ! b} && {c, ! c} && {d, ! d}]
```

Comment: I still don't believe that this is not automatic :P Are you really going to put `&& {sym, ! sym}` each time? But +1 for `Tuples` I don't know why I decided to use `Outer`.:)

Comment: @Kuba Frankly I don't understand the question so I wasn't sure what operation was to be done.  I voted for your answer by the way.  I think my code is open ended in that you could have any number of variations in each sublist.

Comment: I have a CNF and BooleanMinimize can simplify it to `a&&!b`. Now I want to perform the revert process.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know how to incorporate `BooleanConvert` here is a walkaround for this case:

```
conv = Or @@ Flatten[Outer[
                           And,
                           {#1},
                           Sequence @@ Transpose[{Not /@ #2, #2}]]
                    , 2] &
```

.

```
conv @@ {a && ! b, {c}}
```

> ```
> (a && ! b && ! c) || (a && ! b && c)
> ```

```
conv @@ {a && ! b, {c, d}}
```

> ```
> (a && ! b && ! c && ! d) || (a && ! b && ! c && d) || (a && ! b && c && ! d) || 
> (a && ! b && c && d)
> ```